# django blog: A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: django

I run the code last it's well,but taday when i input http://127.0.0.1:8000/,it show A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.but I can't find anyerror in settings.py,and i revised the urls.py,then it show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYmj.png)

it seems like there are two question
my urls.py

```html
from django.conf.urls import url,include,patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.views import *
#admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^archive/$',archive),
    url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
                        )
```

my setting.py

```html
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'zzwayk(+k0m-+docu%uigkuymxlde34fx3$=syx#*3-i)8hlel'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-Hans'

TIME_ZONE = 'CCT'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

archive.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}  
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>  
<p>{{ post.timestamp }}</p>  
<p>{{ post.body }}</p>  
{% endfor %}  
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no default (also called root, index or home) url in your  urls.py

If you add something like this to your urls.py:

```
url("^$", views.index),
```

and also add a function named **index** in your views.py, you should have home page.

Alternatively, visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/archive/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ because those are the urls you have something for.